# how to get data in pandas dataframe skipping 2 rows but also getting some data in first row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a CSV data from  URL
The first row contains title which i am not interested but contains date which i need
The second row contains headers of the CSV file which  I dont need

From 3rd line I have data which I need to read.

I can use Skiprows =2 but I will be unable to get date info from CSV file
or is there a way to get date from skipped rows

I tried to read the whole CSV file as data and drop 2 rows. the coumns or not properly formed in first 2 rows and I get error

Is there a way out

Comment: How working `skiprows = [1,2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply read the first line and then use `pandas.read_csv()` to get the CSV data:

```
with open(path) as fd:
    first_line = fd.readline()
    df = pd.read_csv(fd, skiprows=1, header=None)
```

Comment: ApplePie : you mean read the csv file and store it. and then open first line  and then construct dataframe from rest of the file is it